# Basic Boolean Logic -- How to test for condition only if another condition is true

Tags: php, conditional-statements, logic, boolean

I know this is basic boolean logic, but I'm stuck:

I am looping through database results, and for each one I need to check for the following condition:

```
if($old_value != $new_value)
```

If the above is true, the action is:

```
$old_value = $new_value;
```

But there is a secondary condition.  If the row is of type "date", I need to also check that `$new_value` is not empty, but the action is still the same.  Right now, I am doing it like this:

```
if($old_value != $new_value) {
     if($type != date) {
         $old_value = $new_value;
     } elseif(!empty($new_value)) {
         $old_value = $new_value;
     }
```

I've oversimplified the above, but really that one-line action is actually several lines that I know I don't need to repeat based on the secondary condition.

But I'm at a loss on what the right way to combine the inner condition with the outer condition.  If I do something like:

```
if(($old_value != $new_value) && ($type == 'date' && !empty($new_value))
```

Then the only time it would return true is when the row is of type date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
  if(($old_value != $new_value) && ($type != 'date' || !empty($new_value))
```

That should do it. Let me know if you need help understanding why.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Specifically, wouldn't the OR in the second clause return true every time that `$new_value` is empty, not just when the type is `date`?

Comment: Yes, it would. The whole expression is true exactly when old_value isn't the same thing as new_value AND (we're either not talking about a date OR we are talking about a date but $new_value is empty).

Comment: Oh I see, it doesn't matter if the `!empty($new_value)` is true or not, since the `$type != 'date'` will also be true, so the condition passes and the action occurs.  It will still take me some time to get it enough to do this blindfolded, but it's starting to make sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Anthony With the blindfold on, think of OR as the else condition

Answer (score 2):

`if(($old_value != $new_value) && ($type != 'date' || ($type == 'date' && !empty($new_value)))`
Maybe this one can be made shorter but I can't think of how.

Comment: The "$type == 'date'" is redundant; why?

Comment: Ah now I see it that was the thing I was talking about. Because the second part of the or is only executed when `$type == 'date'`... However this illustrates the straight forward combination of the conditions better.

Comment: True. Your solution is certainly correct; and mine could be shorter, by an application of De Morgan to the sub-expression.

Comment: @Thomas Carpenter: You should add it to your post. I am curious about the shortening effect because I only see a shift of the !